# Detecting swipes to a specific Timeline Card at Mirror API Glassware

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Is it possible to trigger an event at my server side application(notify callback) when user swiped to a specific timeline card of my glassware?

I wonder this because I want to know if the timeline card is seen if it is possible.

**Detail:** We can define menu items to timeline cards at Mirror API Glassware and selections are passed to our notification callback servlet through Mirror API. Thus we are able to handle those menu item selections at server side and do some stuff. I'm looking for a similar pattern for detecting swipes to my timeline cards if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something you can do with the Mirror API. If you feel it is vitally necessary, you can request it at [the Glass issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/), providing as many details and use cases as possible.

But I would really question why you want to do this and if it is truly a "Glass-like" behavior that your users would be expecting. (And even if the results are actually what you're expecting.) One of the core [design principles](https://developers.google.com/glass/design/principles) is that Glass is a different user experience than non-Glass software. Users are not likely to swipe back to your card very often - they are more likely to see it and handle it shortly after it arrives, and then less likely later. You can't assume that they will see your card at all if they are in the middle of other activities. If they swipe past it, they may be on their way to another card, in either direction, and you don't know if they're on your card on their way to another or not. Glass also tends to expect their wearers to make conscious decisions and actions on their part, and these are reported to your Glassware; there are far fewer cases where passive actions are reported.

If it is important to your user that your card be seen, you may want to consider ways to repeat updating the card, and the timestamp on the card, either with or without a new alert, and have the user explicitly acknowledge seeing it. You should also be conscious about when this may be inappropriate or unexpected and allow the user to tailor it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question to be clear. Actually, I was just wondering if there is a built-in way to that at Mirror API. I was pretty sure that it is not possible. So I've asked this question to make it clear to me and another one who may need this.